# unable to execute /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd: No such file or directory

Tags: xubuntu, raspberrypi

After installing vcgencmd following these instructions (https://pypi.org/project/vcgencmd/), I got a not found error. So, I tried copying the vc folder from another linux build (ALARM) into the /opt folder. Below is the result of that.

```
######################################################################
# Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1022-raspi aarch64) #
######################################################################
ubuntu@SlideShowPi:~$ sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd
sudo: unable to execute /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd: No such file or directory
ubuntu@SlideShowPi:~$ sudo pip3 install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (45.2.0)
ubuntu@SlideShowPi:~$ sudo pip3 install -e .
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode: /home/ubuntu
```

In the attached image, Filezilla shows that the app is there but the OS cannot see it. What do I need to do to install vcgencmd successfully?
[vcgencmd file in /opt/vc/bin/ folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLHSq.png)

Comment: First of all, the pypi module you linked to are python bindings for vcgencmd that let you interact witch vcgencmd from within python. Like many python "bindings", it simply starts vcgencmd in a subprocess under the hood, which means vcgencmd must be installed in the first place. The `pip3 install` command didn't work because you are supposed to run it inside the source code directory, but you are probably not interested in the python bindings anyway.

Comment: As for the other problem: "No such file or directory" doesn't necessarily mean that the specified executable doesn't exist, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949268/4325768) explains.

Comment: Thank you danzel for the definition of what is happening. Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem. I tried the `pip3 install` command in the source code directory but it still could not find the app/binding. As for under the hood, my app is failing to execute this: `temp_proc = subprocess.Popen(args=['/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd display_power 0'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` where the executable vcgencmd is located, as I showed in the attached illustration. Any other suggestions would greatly appreciated.

Comment: As for "thie answer" above, I got the following error when trying the cmake solution: `CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/vc/bin" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

Comment: I don't know what "cmake solution" you mean, but the `/opt/vc/bin` folder certainly doesn't contain any source code. The problem is most likely that the folder you copied was built for a different architecture or you are missing libraries. According to the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi), there is an unofficial PPA you can use to install `libraspberrypi-bin` package which contains `vcgencmd`.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 20.04 vcgencmd is included in an existing package:
`apt install libraspberrypi-bin`

For a script to decode the result, [this](https://gist.github.com/aallan/0b03f5dcc65756dde6045c6e96c26459) is working for me.

Comment: This works well. If a specific user will run the vcgencmd command (without sudo) then the user needs to be a member of the group video. I needed to do 1. sudo usermod -aG video <user> and 2. reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem reported above is to use Ubuntu 20.10 that already has `vcgencmd` configured and operational. In my first attempt to use this version, I found that Kivy fade transition was jerky and not smooth which caused me to abort using this version. What I found in my second attempt to use 20.10 is that only the first Kivy fade exhibited the jerky transition but subsequent fades were smooth and acceptable. One other note regarding my comments above is that `vcgencmd` is installed in `/usr/bin` on this version of Ubuntu and not `/opt/vc/bin`.